# how to insert any utf-8 char in lstlisting? especially '⮀', a character without LaTeX equivalent

Tags: listings, unicode

I need to insert a text with ⮀character (u+2b80), in a document. Is there any way?

I've tried: `\literate {⮀}{{???}}1` but can't find what to write instead of `???`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Sauce Code Powerline}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\begin{document}
I can't write ⮀ - \char"2B80

\begin{lstlisting}
a listing with ⮀ symbol
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

only cross in squares appear nothing like http://graphemica.com/%E2%AE%80 what i need (not leftrightarrows but leftwards triangle-headed arrow over rightwards triangle-headed arrow (U+2B80)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, as long as the font you're using has the character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Symbola}
\begin{document}
\char"2B80
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't need to add leftrightarrows but "leftwards triangle-headed arrow over rightwards triangle-headed arrow (U+2B80)" http://graphemica.com/%E2%AE%80 I use a powerline font in xetex but this char doesnt appear

Answer (score 1):

Look up a suitable symbol http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf and then use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings,amssymb}
\lstset{literate ={⮀}{$\leftrightarrows$}1}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
a listing with ⮀ symbol
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following package

```
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
```

Or provide an MWE that the community can try to solve your problem.

Comment: \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Sauce Code Powerline}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\begin{document}
I can't write ⮀ - \char"2B80

\begin{lstlisting}
a listing with ⮀ symbol
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

only cross in squares appear