# Up Arrow not showing in listingsutf8

Tags: listings, listingsutf8

```latex
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes } 
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes } if changed('bbl')
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes } if changed('toc')
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listingsutf8,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\lstset{literate ={↑}{$\uparrow$}1}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction to MATLAB}

\subsection*{Exercise 1.3}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]
>> z = 25-(100-7exp(5+cos(pi/3))
 z = 25-(100-7exp(5+cos(pi/3))
             ↑
Error: Invalid use of operator.

Did you mean: z = 25-(100-7*exp  (5+cos(pi/3)))
>> z = 25-(100-7*exp  (5+cos(pi/3)))

z =

   1.6378e+03
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I've tried following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275395/212259) and still my upwards arrow is invisible:

[image: Screenshot of the listing in PDF form]

#### **Edit**

After changing my first two `usepackage` lines to:

```latex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

And removing the `lstset`, all Unicode characters now properly show, but the arrow is not put where it should be (it is at the end of the previous line, not pointing from the `d` to the `7`):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I just copied your code into Overleaf and it worked (I've got an upwards arrow pointing from the "d" of invalid to the 7 above)...

Comment: I'm using TeXWorks on Windows with MiKTeX and compiling with arara via LuaHBLaTeX